# Very slow response times from sonarqube server

Tags: java, sonarqube, response-time, sonarqube-ops

Running SonarQube 5.3 server and I'm having trouble with incredibly slow response times and as a result a lot of socket timeout errors from various job scanners. Just to give some perspective, SonarQube is running on a Windows 7 box (don't ask), so is Jenkins (in a separate instance of tomcat)

Response times from Jenkins: <0.1 seconds on average

Response times from SonarQube: 3-30 seconds, with average around 9-12 second range

SonarQube is installed as a Windows service and so is Tomcat where Jenkins is running.

The database server that SQ is running against is Oracle, and I really doubt that's the source of latency as the Oracle server is both fast and local... Here're the jvm opts for sq

`sonar.web.javaOpts=-Xmx1536m -Xms256m -XX:MaxPermSize=160m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -server -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=false -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`

Running on `java 1.8_u45`

I'm  kinda at a loss as I don't know how I can improve response time? (Other than by maybe running it on other hardware/os.)

Comment: By the way, since I've got the attention of someone from SonarSource Team, it would be great if I could run sq in my own tomcat... I can almost see this as being an alternative to improving response time. I know this way of running sq is no longer supported, but I think dropping said support is a poor decision

Comment: If I correctly understand, web server is slow and by consequence scanner is slow to initialise and send report ? In this case to help investigating server issue, you can enable TRACE logs to get execution time of SQL and Elasticsearch requests (see sonar.log.level in conf/sonar.properties). In complement you can also log the response time of HTTP requests (see %D in sonar.web.accessLogs.pattern).

Comment: The authentication stack can also be checked if it connects to external systems (LDAP, OpenId, ...).

Comment: Checking system information (Administration > System > System Info) can also help.

Comment: I think all communication with sq is "web" so why you qualify it? For scanners sometimes they complete, but usually they fail with socket timeout... My guess is because response time is so slow... Does that make sense or something else not clear? I enabled extra logging so we will see what happens tomorrow (I run analysis over night)

Comment: Your problem is not clear. What does "Response times from SonarQube" mean ?

Comment: Response time(s) (plural, because they are averaged), how do you not know what "response time" means? The time it takes for sonarqube to respond to a request. In this case a simple http get on a url... What else can "response time" mean to you?

Comment: Whenever I've had this kind of problem, it *was* in fact the database (especially if it wasn't slow from the beginning). Our Oracle admin recalculated the optimizer statistics or whatever and fixed it.

Comment: Good news, thanks for information. The doubt about response time was due to the fact you mentioned scanners. This is a side-effect that does not relate to the root problem.

Comment: Simon, you are wrong: response to a scanner is no different from a response to a browser. Both are coming from the same system/process (and I am not doing anything distributed or load balancing here), and if your socket connections keep timing out, the first thing you need to look at is latency (aka response time)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to improve response time from the server greatly by doing the following:

1. Restart (scheduled this daily)
2. Schedule a process to periodically poll the server (just a shell script executing curl and logging the response time every few minutes)

There are still some discrepancies, which I need to analyze, but after restarting sq, the average latency went down significantly (average response in ~0.6 seconds vs. 10+), it's still a bit slow imo, but as sq is only used internally, I'm ok with it. Most importantly, none of the scanner jobs failed. Before the restart the failure rate for jobs with socket timeout was about 60%

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can add file to exclude to narrow down the scans.

Try to exclude file that you don't need.
https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/

Also i found scan tend to be way faster, if you disable sonar scm

Project->Project Settings -> SCM -> Disabed the SCM sensor (checked it)

sonar.scm.disabled = true